# no error with the stored procedure, but database doesn't update(Access)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, stored-procedures

i'm trying to update some informations in my database through a stored procedure called in asp.net(C#), i'm using an Access dataBase. it's a shoppingCart. i want to update the quantity of an item once it's already in the shoppingCart. i even use a message to be displayed if something goes wrong or not. it displayed that it succeded but the change doesn't happen. i got the same problem also when i try to add an existing item in the shopping cart. the update doesn't execute and i got no error! but it seems clear to me !

```
//méthode pour mettre à jour les données dans la table
public static bool MajProduit(string produit, int qte)
{
    //on obtient l'objet configuré DbCommande
    DbCommand m_cmd = LibAccesGenerique.CreerCmd();
    //on établit la procédure stockée
    if (qte <= 0)
        m_cmd.CommandText = "ShoppingCartDeleteProduits";
    else
        m_cmd.CommandText = "ShoppingCartUpdateProduit";
    //on créer les paramètres
    DbParameter m_param = m_cmd.CreateParameter();
    m_param.ParameterName = "@CartID";
    m_param.Value = ShoppingCartId;
    m_param.DbType = DbType.String;
    m_param.Size = 36;
    m_cmd.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    //on en crée un autre produit
    m_param = m_cmd.CreateParameter();
    m_param.ParameterName = "@Produit";
    m_param.Value = produit;
    m_param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    m_cmd.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    //parametre qté
    m_param = m_cmd.CreateParameter();
    m_param.ParameterName = "@Quantite";
    m_param.Value = qte;
    m_param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    m_cmd.Parameters.Add(m_param);
    //on retourne vrai si l'opération réussie
    try
    {
        //on execute la procédure stockée et retourne vrai, si la méthode s'est bien exécutée
        return (LibAccesGenerique.ExecuteNonQuery(m_cmd) != -1);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is my method for updating item. it's only working with the delete procedure.
here is my update stored procedure(query in msaccess):

```
UPDATE ShoppingCart SET Quantite = @Quantite, DateAjoute = NOW()
WHERE ProduitID = @ProduitID AND CartID = @CartID;
```

here is the delete procedure:

```
DELETE *
FROM ShoppingCart
WHERE CartID = @CartID and ProduitID = @ProduitID;
```

Comment: djasy3 - I think we need to see your stored procedure(s). What error do you get when trying Update. Adding code to your catch to show any exception messages may help in debugging this.

Comment: @Mych: if i try to update directly from the database, it is working correctly... that's what i don't understand.

Comment: OK.... string produit, int qte yet your params for produit is....m_param.Value = produit;
    m_param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    m_cmd.Parameters.Add(m_param); should that not string also?

Comment: Check to see if the returned result for the ExecuteNonQuery is zero. That means it executed correctly (without an error) but nothing got updated. Could you also display the Delete stored procedure? I'm just wondering why that works and the other one doesn't.

Comment: @Mych: no! because i retreive the id of the value of the variable produit from the website through the Request.QueryString[""] method, but in my table, it's a 'int'.
@ Danexxtone: ok, i'm going to put it!

Comment: Hello! :D
i just resolved the problem, thank you for your posts.
The problem was with the order of the parameters. so i was supposed to put them in order like they're placed in the database. i did it and it worked!